# EC2: Deploying a django project with a apache server

Tags: python, django, git, apache, amazon-ec2

I have set up an ec2 instance and I'm able to connect to it via ssh. I've installed apache, django, git and all the necessary dependencies. 
I've managed to clone a git repository which is located in /home/ubuntu/.
I've also set up the configuration file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hyper-blog.conf.
This is my hyper-blog.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ec2-52-11-240-28.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ServerAlias ec2-52-11-240-28.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/static/
alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/media/
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/static">
Require all granted
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
 <Directory "/home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/media">
 Require all granted
Options -Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/hyper-blog>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.hyperiondev.com%{REQUEST_URI}
WSGIDaemonProcess hyper-blog python-path=/home/ubuntu/hyper-blog:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
WSGIProcessGroup hyper-blog
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/hyper-blog/hyper-blog/wsgi.py
```

The problem is when I go to my public domain: ec2-52-11-240-28.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com it takes a while to load and eventually does not render anything.

I need to know how to get my application up and running. I've tried this documentation on digital ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04,
but still doesn't work. 
How can I get my application working without installing virtualenv?

Comment: Confirm that the python version is same as required in wsgi and your app; check the `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` file (`${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` is `/var/log/apache2`).

Comment: What's the point of that RewriteRule?

Comment: Try adding ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. Some third party Python extension modules will not work in sub interpreters and the result is it will hang and not return anything. That directive forces use of main interpreter context and avoids the problem.